# LibreOffice Headless

Tags: libreoffice, phpword

I am trying to convert .docx file to .pdf using the pdfgear as described in https://github.com/phpgearbox/pdf. This component defaults to libre-office-headless. I installed LibreOffice5 in my computer at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5

with its binary lying at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program.

Then in my Controller method i have:

```
$pdf = Gears\Pdf::convert($temp_filename);
shell_exec('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf $temp_filename');
```

The first statement is resulting to the error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: The libreoffice command ("/usr/bin/libreoffice") was not
>   found or is not executable by the current user!

While the next line is resulting to nothing (no error and no pdf document)!

How can i install libre-office-headless to ensure that the first line of code runs successfully? I hope you understand my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the pdfgear source code there are a number of locations hard coded that you might need to adapt. They seem to be written with a normal Linux distro installation of LibreOffice in mind.

One case that seems related to your problem is https://github.com/phpgearbox/pdf/blob/master/src/Pdf/Docx/Converter/LibreOffice.php#L73

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that. Let me try to see if absolute paths to the soffice in windows would work